# how to stop images from shifting positions in gridview on an android app

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, android-alertdialog, shift

I have a GridView that uses an adapter to set ImageViews and when I open up an AlertDialog and focus on its TextView, the images in the GridView shift positions. How do I stop that from happening?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private String[] directory;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, String[] d) {
    this.context = c;
    this.directory = d;
}

public int getCount() {
    return directory.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return directory[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    System.gc();
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.iblock, null);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.foodImage);
        BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfo.inSampleSize = 2;
        iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(directory[position], bfo));

        TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.foodName);
        String[] s = directory[position].split("[\\/.]+");

    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }
    return v;
}
}


protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_SEARCH_ID:
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View searchView = factory.inflate(R.layout.searchbar2, null);

        final EditText searchfield = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.searchfield);

        ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) searchView.findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SearchResults.class);
                i.putExtra("query", searchfield.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchResults.this)
            .setView(searchView)
            .create();
        Window win = ad.getWindow();
        win.setGravity(48);
        return ad;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `View` recycling is broken. When you are given a `View` to recycle, you still need to bind your data to it (in this case, putting the image in the `ImageView`). The only part you can skip when recycling a `View` is inflating the layout.

Comment: thanks, i found that out too, i moved the set imageviews and set textviews down below the if/else

Comment: Do you know how to turn off view recycling ? Because i used an asynctask to load images from url, and it keep shifting.